# Strange "changeable" results in loop in R

Tags: r

**Update2**

The second `set.seed(i)` should be replaced as `set.seed(i+1)`, or whatever another new random series. If not, `s3 <- sum(data$gene == 0 & data$cancer == 1)` will always be `0`, since the number smaller than `0.08` will be smaller than `0.39`.

I did't correct my original question code because this matter is not related to this post's core question.

**Update**

`set.seed(i)` is added twice since there are two random number generations, i.e., `random1` and `random2`. However, the results among operations still changeable, which is strange.

**Background:**

the codes below is about [odds ratios](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nm0G-1uJzA). But the focus point is not statistic here. Instead, I find the results changed (!) among some operations which are actually the same (I suppose that they are in fact not, but I cannot figure it out).

**Code:**

```
gene <- vector(length = 500, mode = "integer")
cancer <- vector(length = 500, mode = "integer")
data <- data.frame(gene, cancer)

odd_withMutate <- vector(length = 20, mode = "numeric")
odd_noMutate   <- vector(length = 20, mode = "numeric")
result <- data.frame(odd_withMutate, odd_noMutate)

for (i in 1:20) {
  # set.seed(12)   
  # set.seed(16)   
  set.seed(i)
  random1 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  # set.seed(12)   
  # set.seed(16)
  set.seed(i)   # add this instruction
  random2 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  for (j in 1:500) {
    if (random1[j] < 0.39){
      data[j,1] <- 1
    }
    if (random2[j] < 0.08){
      data[j,2] <- 1
    }
  }
  s1 <- sum(data$gene == 1 & data$cancer == 1)  # has the mutated gene & has cancer  
  s2 <- sum(data$gene == 1 & data$cancer == 0) 
  s3 <- sum(data$gene == 0 & data$cancer == 1)
  s4 <- sum(data$gene == 0 & data$cancer == 0)
  result[i,]$odd_withMutate <- s1/s2
  result[i,]$odd_noMutate   <- s3/s4    
}
```

**Different operations:**

Operation #1:

If I run the code above, the 12th row of `odd_noMutate` in `result` will be `0`, the 16th will be `NaN`. Then I tried to see what happened, so I use `set.seed(12)` or `set.seed(16)` to check (Operation #2 & #3). But the `0` and `NaN` disappeared! I mean, in Operation #2, `0.1638418  0` is not `1.5075377  0`. In Operation #3, `0.2830189   0` is not `2.4013605  NaN`.

Operation #2:

the changed part of code is:

```
  set.seed(12)   #odd_noMutate = 0
  # set.seed(16)   #odd_noMutate = NaN
  # set.seed(i)
  random1 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  set.seed(12)
  # set.seed(16)
  # set.seed(i)   # add this instruction
  random2 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
```

Operation #3:

```
  # set.seed(12)   #odd_noMutate = 0
  set.seed(16)   #odd_noMutate = NaN
  # set.seed(i)
  random1 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  # set.seed(12)
  set.seed(16)
  # set.seed(i)   # add this instruction
```

Operation #4:

I find that even changed the `i` in my code will make results totally different (Shouldn't it be the subset of the original result?). It is the Operation #4. Specifically, `0.3092105  0` is not `1.5075377  0`; `0.7562724    0` is not `2.4013605  NaN`.

```
for (i in 10:20) {
  # set.seed(12)   #odd_noMutate = 0
  # set.seed(16)   #odd_noMutate = NaN
  set.seed(i)
  random1 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  # set.seed(12)
  # set.seed(16)
  set.seed(i)   # add this instruction
  random2 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
```

The results among these operations are shown below:
[image: Result]

Comment: If you get 0 valuese for sum in the denominator, there can be `Inf`.  also, if both are 0, it would be NaN `5/0#
[1] Inf
> 0/0
[1] NaN`

Comment: For seed issues, you may check `RNGkind`

Comment: @akrun I find one of my errors when trying to repeat (debug). I should use seed instruction everytime I generate a random number to ensure the same values. However, OP#1 ~ OP#4 were still different, which is strange.

Comment: Call `set.seed` ONCE, outside the loop, and never touch it again. Do NOT call it 40 times.

Comment: @HongOoi Hi, it seems the random numbers should be made everytime the loop is run, because every loop is run as a separate simulation for sampling from the population (i.e., do 20 times of sampling, each sampling includes 500 people).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some previous values in `data` remain and are reused. Maybe your problem are solved remaking `data` every for loop (i). (putting `data <- data.frame(gene, cancer)` into for loop).

```
gene <- vector(length = 500, mode = "integer")
cancer <- vector(length = 500, mode = "integer")
# data <- data.frame(gene, cancer)

odd_withMutate <- vector(length = 20, mode = "numeric")
odd_noMutate   <- vector(length = 20, mode = "numeric")
result <- data.frame(odd_withMutate, odd_noMutate)

for (i in 1:20) {
  data <- data.frame(gene, cancer)  # remaking data every time
  # set.seed(12)   
  # set.seed(16)   
  set.seed(i)
  random1 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  # set.seed(12)   
  # set.seed(16)
  set.seed(i)   # add this instruction
  random2 <- runif(500, min = 0, max = 1)
  for (j in 1:500) {
    if (random1[j] < 0.39){
      data[j,1] <- 1
    }
    if (random2[j] < 0.08){
      data[j,2] <- 1
    }
  }
  s1 <- sum(data$gene == 1 & data$cancer == 1)  # has the mutated gene & has cancer  
  s2 <- sum(data$gene == 1 & data$cancer == 0) 
  s3 <- sum(data$gene == 0 & data$cancer == 1)
  s4 <- sum(data$gene == 0 & data$cancer == 0)
  result[i,]$odd_withMutate <- s1/s2
  result[i,]$odd_noMutate   <- s3/s4    
}
```

### [ADDITION]

`for` loop doesn't have own environment unlike function.
So handling in `for` loop directly affects Global env objects such as your `data`.
You **partly** overwrited `data` of Global env by if statement and it was referred in next loop.

Here is my simple example;

```
data <- data.frame(gene = vector(length = 5, mode = "integer"))
keep_of_process <- list()

for(i in 1:2) {

  set.seed(i)
  random_val <- runif(5, 0, 1)

  for(j in 1:5) {
    if(random_val[j] < 0.39) {
      data[j, 1] <- 1
    }

    keep_of_process[[i]] <- data.frame(random = random_val,
                                       gene = data$gene)
  }
}


do.call("cbind", keep_of_process)  # just to merge process to show
 # left is i = 1 and right is i = 2

     random gene    random gene
1 0.2655087    1 0.1848823    1
2 0.3721239    1 0.7023740    1
3 0.5728534    0 0.5733263    0
4 0.9082078    0 0.1680519    1
5 0.2016819    1 0.9438393    1
```

Please see row 2. In i = 2, `random` is 0.7023740 but gene is 1 (previous result retains).

So to do what you want (from my understanding), you need to remake `data` (my answer) or completely overwrite `data` by if statement, such as

```
if(random_val[j] < 0.39) {
      data[j, 1] <- 1
    } else {
      data[j, 1] <- 0
    }
```

Comment: The problem is solved! Could you explain a little bit about why "remake" data everytime can do it? I mean, just the movement into the loop, and then changeable results disappeared ...

Comment: @TX; OK, I wrote an additional part.

Comment: Amazing! It's a very important aspect (Global env and partly overwrite) that I didn't notice before. It makes even the statistical error (0, 1 misclassification) here. Thank you so much!